# Model Binding Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have 2 methods like this

```
public ViewResult Detail(int Id)
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            Poll PollDetail = context.Polls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
            PollDetail.Answers = new List<Answer>();
            Context Context = new Context();
            PollDetail.Answers = Context.Answers.Where(x => x.PollId == PollDetail.Id).ToList();
            return View("../Home/Index", PollDetail);
        }
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PollVote(Poll CurrentPoll)
    {
        Context Context = new Context();
        foreach (Answer item in CurrentPoll.Answers)
        {
            item.VoteCount = item.VoteCount + 1;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

There cshtml. so there is no problem to this section.

```
<div class="container">
   @Html.Partial("Header")
    @if (Model == null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("CreatePoll")
    }
    else
    {
        using (@Html.BeginForm("PollVote", "Poll", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PollVoteForm" }))
        {
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 pageHeader">
                    <h2>SORU:</h2>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Question, Model.Question, new { @class = "question-input", @id = "question" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="answers" class="row-fluid">

               @foreach (Answer answer in Model.Answers)
                {
                    <p class="external">

                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => answer.Content, answer.Content, new { @name = "rb", @class = "answer-radio", @id = "answer-" + answer.Counter, @checked = "false" })
                        @Html.Label(answer.Content, new { @for = "answer-" + answer.Counter })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => answer.Content)

                    </p>
                }

            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6"></div>
                <div class="span5">
                    <input type="submit" value="Oyla" class="btnPS" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }


   <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Poll model perfectly binded. But i cant back any data. when i submit form in index.cshtml. CurrentPoll model comes null. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Can you show code of the form that is submitted to `PollVote`?

Comment: Can you show code for index.cshtml

Comment: Please show your code in index.cshtml and the definition of Poll class

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net MVC require propertioes on your model in order for the model binding. Hence check your model and ensure all members are exposed as properties.

Eg: You change your model to something like below.

```
public class Poll 
{
    public Answer Answers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did something like this

public IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot the get/set properties in one class, and it drove me batty for 2 hours attempting to resolve it.